# Wordpress pingback attack

Tags: ddos, wordpress, nginx

I am getting Wordpress pingback attach on my server. I tried to put if condition on nginx to block deny all requests that contains "Wordpress" in the header. It works fine but still nginx get millions of requests per second and it is useful solution. Then I tried following solution that works better:

There are thousands of IPs involved in the attack on only port 80. I used following rule to block this attack:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m recent --update --seconds 600 --name PINGBACK --rsource -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "WordPress/" --algo kmp -m recent --set --name PINGBACK --rsource
```

This rule is [from this site](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/219820/dealing_with_recent_wp_pingback_ddosattacks_using/). It works all fine. However, the IPs keep coming back and my system tried to keep blocking the packets. I want to log the list of all these IPs which contain "WordPress" in the header. Is it possible to do it?

### EDIT

dmesg output

```
net_ratelimit: 346 callbacks suppressed
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
net_ratelimit: 483 callbacks suppressed
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
net_ratelimit: 5 callbacks suppressed
```

Comment: Have you checked `dmesg`?

Comment: mchid, I am a noob and sorry don't know much about dmesg. Also, I have deleted the question on askubuntu to avoid any duplicates.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `dmesg`. If you find a word like `DROP` that you want to search the results for or `WordPress`, you can do that like so: `dmesg | grep DROP` or `dmesg | grep WordPress` or you can use regex with egrep to search for more than one word like so: `dmesg | egrep 'DROP|WordPress'`

Comment: @mchid, I added dmesg output in my question. That's all it produced. Running grep didn't produce any output. I am not sure why it's full or what does it mean though.

Comment: maybe this will help http://gr8idea.info/os/tutorials/security/iptables5.html

Comment: if you are use apache can you write block the xmlrpc.php for everyone?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `/proc/net/ipt_recent/PINGBACK` (or `/proc/net/xt_recent/PINGBACK` in some installations) contains the list of all IP addresses seen as WordPress bots during last 600 seconds. This is a text file which is updated automatically in real time by the system.

You can either collect data from this file over some period of time or set an interval bigger than 600 seconds in your iptables rule.